# Forward to a new page based on the selection from a drop-down list without using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp

I am trying to remove JavaScript from my JSP. Currently i am using something like this to forward to the page i need based on the selection in the drop-down list.

```
function STFS() {
    var url = document.stform.typeOptions.options[document.stform.typeOptions.selectedIndex].value;
    if (url!=0) {
        window.location=url;
    }
}
```

How can i do the same thing without using javascript.
I tried setting the window.location in the 'select onChange' as follows:

```
<select name="typeOptions" onChange="window.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
```

But when i submit the form, it doesn't go to the expected url. I must be missing something. 
This is a portlet environment and the URL is relatively long. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You know doing that in the onChange is still using Javascript, right?

Comment: But what you tried in onChange attribute is also Javascript !?

Comment: ummm by using the onChange event (not to mention the whole window.location bit and using dom elements to find your url value) you are using javascript. Is there a specific reason you don't want to use js? What are you trying to accomplish by doing it this way?

Comment: great! that's so noob of me. thanks. the reason for no javascript is to make the site work even when javascript is disabled. since the amount of script involved in this page is just that function, i thought it would be better to get rid of that. but, if anyone can suggest any other way to achieve this. i'll be glad. i am open to using <noscript> as well.

Comment: You don't have to remove JavaScript entirely, you can use it to improve user experience. For example, if you use the redirecting trick in BalusC's answer, you can add a JavaScript to take user to new page without having to press the submit button.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Use `onchange` instead of `onChange` (not the real problem since lot of browsers are forgiving on this, but it is plain incorrect) and ensure that you're running the code you think you're running (i.e. you're not running an old or browser-cached version) and that you're really changing the dropdown item instead of plain pressing the form submit button (the `onchange` doesn't run when you submit the form).</strike>

---

**Update** as per the comment

> great! that's so noob of me. thanks. the reason for no javascript is to make the site work even when javascript is disabled. since the amount of script involved in this page is just that function, i thought it would be better to get rid of that. but, if anyone can suggest any other way to achieve this. i'll be glad. i am open to using  as well

Change it as follows:

```
<form action="redirect">
    <select name="url">
        ...
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

with a `RedirectServlet` class which is mapped on an URL pattern of `/redirect` and does basically the following job in `doGet()` method:

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getParameter("url"));
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC. I tried your suggestion with no luck. It's probably because of the way i asked the question. But, in any case i actually went back to basics and submitted the form with the id i need in the select option value instead of the entire url. and did a request.getAttribute in the controller. Thanks for all the comments guys.